# Flutter showDatePicker show year selection first

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I use `showDatePicker` method to show the date picker, but how to open date picker that show/open the year selection by default, before going to select month & date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the property `initialDatePickerMode` to `DatePickerMode.year` ([doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DatePickerMode-class.html))

**Code Sample:**

```dart
showDatePicker(
   context: context,
   initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
   initialDate: initialDate,
   firstDate: DateTime(firstDate),
   lastDate: DateTime(lastDate),
);
```